# 3D-Scatter Plots (Highcharts) too slow to update new data

Tags: javascript

I am working on 3D scatter plots using HTML javascript and Flask . 
When I try to change the data points to be plotted , it takes too much time to reflect those changes on 3D scatter plots(even if I am working with number of data points as low as 10) .... Can someone help me on that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Take a look at [Plotly](https://plot.ly/highcharts-alternative/) as an alternative!

Comment: Thank @Miklós Tusz for responding .... Just want to confirm , Is Plotly efficient enough to handle large data without much delays ?

Comment: _Large_ is a relative term, but it will work with realistically large sets. As your dataset size increases, render and calculation time will understandably as well, but by using the WebGL types, most datasets can be plotted without issue.